# How to set root password on Yocto / Poky image?

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto

I am building an image with Yocto/Poky release Daisy 1.6.3.
What is the correct way or config file where to set the root password? The default password is empty and I can't find a place where to specify it.

Comment: Anyone care to explain the downvotes 2 years after the question was asked?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is what you have to do in your recipe.

```
inherit extrausers
EXTRA_USERS_PARAMS = "usermod -P p@ssw0rd root;"
```

where p@ssw0rd is the password you want root user to have.

[This link](https://wiki.yoctoproject.org/wiki/FAQ:How_do_I_set_or_change_the_root_password) may help you.

As "debug-tweaks"'s goal is to set root's password empty, you must remove it from your EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES.

Comment: I realize this is a few years old, but it's important to point out that this class and variable are intended at the _image level_ recipe, not a package, etc. ([rocko](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.4.3/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#ref-classes-extrausers))

Answer (score 7):

As of Poky 4.0.7, none of the answers here work because the `-P` clear text password flag is no longer supported as per [this commit](https://github.com/openembedded/openembedded-core/commit/759df7395908f18b3b68f28d043ac9ebd42dd0c8). You will get an error message like `usermod: prefix must be an absolute path`. Now, only the `-p` encrypted password flag is supported. To set your root password to `password` add below to your `conf/local.conf` file:

```
INHERIT += "extrausers"
EXTRA_USERS_PARAMS = "usermod -p '\$1\$EZkCDWad\$eEMhB36cFCOeRGXvtP3t81' root;"
```

you can generate your own password string with `openssl passwd -1` but note that `$` needs to be escaped with `\` as shown in the example.

Comment: I'm using SHA512 to hash the password but not working. my question is here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/754866/yocto-linux-root-logging-error-libcrypt-does-not-support-md5-or-sha512
any help

Answer (score 5):

As of Poky 2.1.2; to set the root password the following instructions need to be added to local.conf:

```
INHERIT += "extrausers"
EXTRA_USERS_PARAMS = "usermod -P p@ssw0rd root;"
```

No need to remove `debug-tweaks`

Answer (score 4):

In your image recipe:

1. Set a plain password:

```
inherit extrausers  
EXTRA_USERS_PARAMS = "usermod -P MyPass root;"
```

2. Or set a hashed password (notice that insert \ before dollar signs):

```
inherit extrausers  
EXTRA_USERS_PARAMS = "usermod -p '\$6\$3trMG9KVzGF3942L\$pHeO/r4/RIEFU1tZzoPXYlJLHNvmeJFZdIwQCcTrZFq5kpIgTxoEOJBO5iYEvLzeMjhZRtXhTPbOD4RFAelwk0' root;"
```

Note: for hashing your plain password, use can use openssl:

```sh
$ openssl passwd -6
Password:
Verifying - Password:
$6$3trMG9KVzGF3942L$pHeO/r4/RIEFU1tZzoPXYlJLHNvmeJFZdIwQCcTrZFq5kpIgTxoEOJBO5iYEvLzeMjhZRtXhTPbOD4RFAelwk0
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is method I used which does not use the -P switch on the usermod command. 
You must use the following form:

```
EXTRA_USERS_PARAMS = "usermod -p $(openssl passwd p@ssw0rd) root;"
```

The usermod -P command does not work in my version of linux.

See [How do i change the root password in the Yocto dora bitbake system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47850368/how-do-i-change-the-root-password-in-the-yocto-dora-bitbake-system)

Answer (score 1):

Add the below linw at your `conf/local.conf` file

```
INHERIT += "extrausers"
EXTRA_USERS_PARAMS = "usermod -P urpassword root;"
```