# How do i change the root password in the Yocto dora bitbake system?

Tags: passwords, embedded, root, yocto, bitbake

I am working on the Dora branch (Poky 1.2) of Yocto and need to work on this branch only.

I need to change the blank root password to some other value in order to prevent a security hole in the image during development.

How do I set the root password?

I would like to use the local.conf file.

The method described here does not work:
[How to set root password on Yocto / Poky image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32274163/how-to-set-root-password-on-yocto-poky-image)

Answer (score 1):

Add the below line in your `build/conf/local.conf` or go to your `meta-dir` and add the below line for taking git patch.

```
INHERIT += "extrausers"
EXTRA_USERS_PARAMS = "useradd admin; \
                      usermod -p $(openssl passwd abc123) admin; \
                      usermod -p $(openssl passwd knockknock) root; \
                     "
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that the early version of poky does not accept the -P switch for the usermod in the local.conf file.  (Maybe this is because I use Linux kernel 3.0)

In order to change the root password I needed to do the following:
(I also added an admin user)

In my poky/build/conf/local.conf file I added the following lines:

```
INHERIT += "extrausers"
EXTRA_USERS_PARAMS = "useradd admin; \
                      usermod -p $(openssl passwd abc123) admin; \
                      usermod -p $(openssl passwd knockknock) root; \
                     "
```

The password for admin is '*abc123*' and the password for root is '*knockknock*'.

I also added a recipe for the openssl to the image from poky/meta/recipes-connectivity/openssl/openssl_1.0.1p.bb